Are there any significant differences between using dataframe.loc and dataframe.append when adding to a pandas dataframe in python?
I am trying to add a new row to a dataframe. This article gives three methods of adding to a dataframe ->
df.loc[len(df.index)] = new_object  
df.append(new_object)  
pandas.concat([df1, df2])

As far as I can tell, the first two do the same thing. I understand that df.concat() is for adding two dataframes together, but is there any difference between df.loc() and df.append()? Are there situations where I should use one over the other? Or are they functionally equivalent?

df.append creates a new dataframe vs df.loc which modifies the existing dataframe

append has been deprecated and not available in latest versions of Pandas.

pd.concat() also creates a new df.

@user19077881 Thanks for the info! The article uses df._append in the actual code, which still exists for some reason. But I'll avoid using it since it's technically deprecated.

Here are some basic differences:

df.loc is creating a new object in the existing DataFrame.

append is also appending a new object into the existing DataFrame. But, as of version 2.0.0, it was deprecated from pandas.

pd.concat does create a new DataFrame that is the concatenation of the two specified DataFrames.


As mentioned here, pd.concat is the fastest approach for large DataFrames.
